# three js - how to make a decagon

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
 var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;

      var object = new THREE.Object3D();
      spherical.set(1000, phi, theta );
      object.position.setFromSpherical( spherical );
      vector.copy( object.position ).multiplyScalar( 2 );
      object.lookAt( vector );
    }
```

This code describes round three.js sphere. How to make a decagon out of it? Thanks

Comment: By "make a decagon out of it" do you mean "create a regular decagon whose vertices are on the circle" ?

Comment: You want that in 2D shape right!

Comment: Use `var decagon = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 10);`